# using dropbox.com for software update

Tags: updates, dropbox, automatic-update

I am looking dropbox.com as an update method for my software which is going to be deployed manually by me among many computers. I am planning to install the software into a drop box folder which can be controlled remotely. So if I place a new version of software into the drop box directory all previous versions of software is automatically updated[this will not replace the old version, a new exe will be deployed without deleting the old version. this will help avoid damages to the requests which are currently processed by the old version exe.].

I am also planning to deploy an dummy application. so any request to the main application will be first received by this dummy application. The dummy application know which version is the latest version and routes the request to the appropriate exe.

Please send your suggestions. Can any one see any disadvantage in this approach?

Comment: Updates/upgrades can be quite tricky. They must not hose any of the client's data. What you are suggesting may work, or you might need something more complex - it all depends on the complexity of a project.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to re-write the question so it is clear what you are asking.

Comment: It also matters which OS you are doing this for

Comment: @mankoff: I think it's pretty clear what he's asking. It's not clear what software he's using, or how complex it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dropbox as a repository for files to be distributed, but you may find a tool designed for the purpose to be simpler to use and manage - have a read about [Wpkg](http://wpkg.org/) which may be suitable

Comment: Thanks Linker. Falmarri from stackoverflow has sent an nice advice."Dropbox really isn't meant to install executables to. Anyone of your users could trash their dropbox and it would destroy every other user's dropbox. And it seems like a massive security hole."

Comment: Plus no modern OS these days allow executables from the Internet to autorun. This is, again, due to security.

Comment: One other piece of data: http://greyhat-security.com/dropbox-insecure-design